Google Ad Manager: The ad request was successful, but no ad was returned due to lack of ad inventory OR Request Error: No ad to show
I've integrated the [react-native-ad-manager](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-ad-manager) library into my React Native app to display banner ads at the two places in the app. 
During testing, both with test ad unit IDs and actual ad unit IDs, the ads displayed correctly. However, after launching the app on the App Store and Play Store, I've encountered an issue where approximately 1 out of 10 times, the ad fails to load, triggering the onAdFailedToLoad function.
The error messages received include:

The ad request was successful, but no ad was returned due to lack of ad inventory.
Request Error: No ad to show.

with error code: 3
Upon investigation, I've confirmed that there is sufficient inventory available, with thousands of Available Impressions with Likely to deliver status. Despite this, the ads intermittently fail to load.
I've tried various troubleshooting steps but haven't been able to resolve the issue. 
Any guidance or workaround would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your assistance in advance.

As the message suggests there were no ads to show. Sometimes you have to wait for few days before the ads start showing.
Referance: https://github.com/sbugert/react-native-admob/issues/349

The error is still there for me after a month. The cause is something else.
